# Prevent garbage collection for managed reference which is used in unmanaged code

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, c++-cli, wrapper

My C# application uses wrapped C++ code for calculations.

C++ header:

```
__declspec(dllexport) void SetVolume(BYTE* data, unsigned int width);
```

C++/CLI wrapper:

```
void SetVolume(array<Byte>^ data, UInt32 width) 
{
    cli::pin_ptr<BYTE> pdata = &data[0];
    pal->SetVolume(pdata, width); 
}
```

C# :

```
public startCalc()
{
    byte[] voxelArr = File.ReadAllBytes("Filtered.rec");
    palw.SetVolume(voxelArr, 490);
    //GC.KeepAlive(voxelArr); makes no sense
}
```

The C++ `SetVolume` function starts **asynchronous** calculations. `voxelArr` is not referenced from the managed side any longer and is garbage collected.

How can I prevent the garbage collection for this reference until the unmanaged code finished it's work without to declare `voxelArr` as global variable? Creating a copy of array isn't an option as there is really a lot of data. Active wait inside of `startCalc()` isn't good too.

Comment: keeping it from being collected is not your only problem, you will also need to prevent it from being moved around in memory. So you also have to pin it (as Reed Copsey suggests)

Comment: @HugoRune I thought `pin_ptr` prevents moving it, doesn't it?

Comment: Do consider if creating a copy isn't the best approach here.  At least you'll be relieved from unpinning it and the GC is a lot happier as well.

Comment: yes, that means it *is* pinned (and also exempt from garbage collection) If you only need it for as long as the cli SetVolume runs, I don't think you need anything else. However it will be unpinned and may be collected or moved as soon as the wrapper setVolume function ends

Comment: @HugoRune I've tried to declare `byte[] voxelArr` as global var and everything worked just fine. After moving it's declaration into the function scope, c++ can't access the memory some time after `palw.SetVolume(voxelArr, 490); ` is executed. Is there some other reason other than it is garbage collected?

Comment: @HansPassant this array contains sometimes more than 10Gb of data, the copy will simply not fit in the memory.

Comment: it is either garbagabe collected or moved to a different address (most likely collected). Since the pin_ptr you use will only last until the wrapper function ends, it is insufficient to prevent either. (edit: if the array is that large, then the garbage collection will not move it, only collect it. But this is an implementation detail of GC that may change without notice, you should pin it anyway.)

Comment: @VladL If it's 10gb, it's not being moved (since it'd be on the LOH), so it's being GC'ed.  That being said, I wouldn't worry about it - you MUST pin it in any case, or do something to prevent it from being GCed

Comment: Well, if it is ten jiggabytes then pinning won't matter, it won't be moved.  Only objects less than 80KB get moved.

Comment: @HansPassant Isn't the cutoff 85,000 bytes [for everything except double arrrays]? (not that it matters)

Comment: Come to think of it, the statement is nonsense.  A managed object can't be larger than 2 jiggabytes, even in 64-bit mode.

Comment: @HansPassant - Good point - you can be over 2gb with gcAllowVeryLargeObjects, but not with a (one dimensional) byte array ;)

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for the info, I tested my code with smaller (700mb) files so couldn't note this. What about unmanaged objects? Do you know a good article about this subject?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`GCHandle.Alloc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1246yz8f.aspx)`(voxelArr,`[`GCHandleType.Pinned`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y4ak54.aspx)`)` to pin the array manually so the GC won't move or clean it.

You would then have to [Free](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle.free.aspx) the handle when you knew the method was complete, which would require some form of callback for the completion.

Comment: thanks, looks like what I need. Does that mean that I do not need to pin `data` variable in c++cli?

Comment: @VladL If you're pinning it in C#, you wouldn't need to pin it in C++.  That being said, the pin_ptr gives you access to the data *as a pointer*, so you likely will still want it to exist.  You could also just persist the pin_ptr on the C++ side, as it's just doing this internally.

Comment: @VladL Note that you can do this entirely in your C++/CLI wrapper instead of doing it in C#, as well.  That'd be my preference, as it'd make the API cleaner...

Answer (score 1):

Another Alternative to your current approach:

Consider making the array global again, create and pin it once at the start, then reuse it whenever you need it. Objects as large as these should not be created on a whim, [pool them](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern). Only unpin and release it when you need to recreate it with a larger size

Storing the object in a global pool will prevent it from being garbage collected. You do not strictly speaking have to worry about pinning an object this large, but do so for consistency

Comment: well, it could be an option, if I had to reuse this array, but I really need it only once to load the data and pass it to c++ calculations.